# cannot install R package

Tags: r, r-package

I hit this error when I try to install rJava package in R. Please help

```
> utils:::menuInstallPkgs()
trying URL 'http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/R/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/rJava_0.9-6.zip'
Content type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' length 3280 bytes
opened URL
downloaded 3280 bytes

Error in read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In unzip(zipname, exdir = dest) : error 1 in extracting from zip file
2: In read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) :
  cannot open compressed file 'rJava/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

Comment: Is your network configured to go through a proxy server? You may need to do `setInternet2` (etc) if so [via](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/How-to-set-proxy-settings-for-R-td2016158.html)

Comment: You can also try downloading the package locally then installing from source

Comment: I did try installing from local drive. No Luck. I get the same error message

Comment: I was able to install after getting admin rights.