# Cannot install R package even with PC Admin rights

Tags: r, ggplot2, installation, package

I have been trying to install `ggplot2` package on my system from a long time. I work in a secure office environment, and thus there are firewall issues/admin right issues that need to be cleared. I am partially aware of this and have taken admin rights to my machine. I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26408623/cannot-install-r-package) and was still without success.
I have not installed R packages on this system before.
Have installed R packages on my personal PC and they work fine.

Code and comments are as follows:

```
> install.packages("ggplot2")
Installing package into ‘D:/Rlib’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘colorspace’, ‘Rcpp’, ‘stringr’, ‘RColorBrewer’, ‘dichromat’, ‘munsell’, ‘labeling’, ‘plyr’, ‘digest’, ‘gtable’, ‘reshape2’, ‘scales’, ‘proto’

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/colorspace_1.2-4.zip'
Content type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' length 1627 bytes
opened URL
downloaded 1627 bytes

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/Rcpp_0.11.3.zip'
Content type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' length 1625 bytes
opened URL
downloaded 1625 bytes

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/stringr_0.6.2.zip'
Content type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' length 1625 bytes
opened URL
downloaded 1625 bytes

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/RColorBrewer_1.1-2.zip'
Content type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' length 1629 bytes
opened URL
downloaded 1629 bytes

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/dichromat_2.0-0.zip'
Content type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' length 1629 bytes
opened URL
downloaded 1629 bytes

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/munsell_0.4.2.zip'
Content type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' length 1627 bytes
opened URL
downloaded 1627 bytes

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/labeling_0.3.zip'
Content type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' length 1625 bytes
opened URL
downloaded 1625 bytes

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/plyr_1.8.1.zip'
Content type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' length 1627 bytes
opened URL
downloaded 1627 bytes

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/digest_0.6.8.zip'
Content type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' length 1629 bytes
opened URL
downloaded 1629 bytes

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/gtable_0.1.2.zip'
Content type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' length 1627 bytes
opened URL
downloaded 1627 bytes

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/reshape2_1.4.1.zip'
Content type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' length 1627 bytes
opened URL
downloaded 1627 bytes

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/scales_0.2.4.zip'
Content type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' length 1629 bytes
opened URL
downloaded 1629 bytes

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/proto_0.3-10.zip'
Content type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' length 1627 bytes
opened URL
downloaded 1627 bytes

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/ggplot2_1.0.0.zip'
Content type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' length 1627 bytes
opened URL
downloaded 1627 bytes

Warning in install.packages :
  error 1 in extracting from zip file
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open compressed file 'colorspace/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection
```

P.S.: I have added a .libPaths() folder where I have full rights. This should negate permission issues, right?

Comment: You could just download the zip files and install locally? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474081/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-from-source

Comment: Try setting `options(internet.info = 0)` and doing the installs again to see what messages come back (you may be able to see what's blocking)

Comment: @CMichael: Cannot download the zip files.. permission issues!

Comment: @hrbrmstr:
Getting the exact error message as earlier

Answer (score 3):

@CMichael is probably correct.  I don't know what got downloaded, but a quick check of any CRAN package onyour list will show that their sizes are far larger than  1625 bytes.  Almost certainly all you got in each case is an error message due to firewall blocking.

Download or sneakernet the zip files and install locally.

Comment: Done
:)

Downloaded zip files and had the admin team install them for me
:P